# How QueryBuilder's select work?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I have a Category that has many Marker. I want to get a category by id with all the markers associated.

I have this query in my Marker's repository:

```
public function findOneByIdJoinedToCategory($id)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
        ->innerjoin('m.category', 'c')
        ->where('c.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

It works as intended, i get the category's data with an array marker with all the marker data. But I don't want all the data field so I tested this query:

```
public function findOneByIdJoinedToCategory($id)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
        ->select('m.id', 'm.name', 'm.description', 'm.vicinity', 'm.geo')
        ->innerjoin('m.category', 'c')
        ->addSelect('c.id', 'c.name')
        ->where('c.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

When I do this, I except to have only the field I selected, but I have an extra array and get this error : ***Call to a member function getCategory() on array***

How do I select my field and get a category with all its marker ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use [Doctrine partial objects](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html) here

So `select` will look something like this

```
->select('partial m.{id, name, description...
```